# Get output of Perforce command run using p4api

Tags: c++, perforce

I am using the Perforce, a.k.a. Helix Core, C++ API to programmatically run a Perforce command.  All the examples I have found so far are brief, and show how to establish a connection to the server and run the command.  But... then what?  How do I access the output of that command?

A simple example:

```
#include <p4/clientapi.h>

// Connect to server.
ClientApi client;
client.SetProtocol( "tag", "" );
client.Init( &e );
if ( e.Test() )
{
  e.Fmt( &msg );
  fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", msg.Text() );
  return;
}

// Run the command.
ClientUser cu;
client.Run( "info", &cu );

// Access the output.
ummm... ?
```

(This question deserves a "p4api" tag.  But, I do not have enough reputation to create a new tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClientUser` object receives the output.  If you run this code from the command line, you'll see the `p4 info` output being printed by the `OutputInfo()` method.

If you want to do something different with the output, subclass `ClientUser` and implement output methods that do something else.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/p4api/chapter.methods.html#clientuser.outputinfo

There are lots of examples of this in the Perforce Workshop.  https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/sam_stafford/deepannotate/DAUserFilelog.cpp

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.